# Webpack can't find webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Webpack 2.2.0 is giving me this error when I try to run an npm script:

> No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option.

I've made sure that webpack.config.js is in the src folder.

```
module.exports = {
entry: './src/app.js',
output: {
    filename: './dist/app.bundle.js'
   }
}
```

[image]

[Here is my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H29Hu.jpg)

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I think the `webpack.config.js` file should go in root, not `./src`. That's your app's source code directory.

Comment: Is your webpack installed locally or globally? Are you executing a webpack  command whilst in /src/ directory (same dir where config file is?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

- move `webpack.config.js` to the root folder instead of `./src` (pointed out by Jared Farrish)
- use the `--config` attribute with the CLI that points to `./src/webpack.config.js`: `webpack --config src/webpack.config.js`